# Creating long root passwords

Tags: sudo, password, root

Lets say I have root password `somepass`. Is there a way to create a script that changes my password to a string consisting of the original password concatenated with itself n times ?

I.e., if n=3, the script should change my password from `somepass` to `somepasssomepasssomepass`.

(The idea is to save time of typing in long passwords if n is a big number.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do it.

```
n=5
p="password"
u="username"
for (( c=1; c<=n; c++)) ; do d=$p$d ; done
echo $u":"$d | sudo chpasswd
```

the `sudo` part is not necessary if you're running this as root.